# AppleScript check if Chrome Extension is installed

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

**Using AppleScript, I need to check if Adblock Plus (ABP) is installed in the Chrome Browser.**
After numerous attempts at trying to figure out how, I have come to the conclusion that it would be relatively easy to check if the ABP "firstRun.html" exists.

Or is there a more reliable script to check if this specific extension is installed?

Here is my script, however **it always returns true**. Please Help.

```
if checkIfABPInstalled() is true then
    log "FOUND"
else
    log "NOT FOUND"
end if


on checkIfABPInstalled()
    try
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            if ("chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/firstRun.html") exists then
                return true
            else
                return false
            end if
        end tell
    on error
        return false
    end try
end checkIfABPInstalled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome's AppleScript Dictionary doesn't have a direct method to check for extensions, so you need to test for the Adblock Plus extension in a different way.

If the Adblock Plus extension is installed, then the `adblockplus.js` file will exist within the `"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/` directory structure. So I'd test for its existence and the example AppleScript *code* below does that.

```
set fileExists to do shell script "find \"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions\" -iname adblockplus.js 2>/dev/null"

if fileExists is not "" then
    display dialog "Adblock Plus is installed." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "Adblock Plus is not installed." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon caution
end if
```